# SOFR Transition for Future Flow Transactions

Tags: libor, sofr, libor-cessation, securitization

I’m looking for some papers/articles for the transition from LIBOR to SOFR for future flow transactions/securitizations (such as Diversified Payment Rights).
Would be happy if you could share some as there are very few sources on the SOFR transition of this product type.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the reference for the Fed sponsored committee that is managing the transition for USD Libor.  I don’t see any reference to that specific product, but they do discuss securitizations.

https://www.newyorkfed.org/arrc